How many roots has the equation $z = \varphi(z)$ in $|z| < 1$ if for $|z| \leq 1$, $\varphi(z)$ is analytic and satisfies $|\varphi(z)| < 1$?
Problem How many roots has the equation $z = \varphi(z)$ in $|z| < 1$ if for $|z| \leq 1$,  $\varphi(z)$ is analytic and satisfies $|\varphi(z)| < 1$?

I'm suspecting this is an application of Rouche's Theorem. In particular, I'm using

Rouche's Theorem: Let $\gamma$ be homologous to zero in $\Omega$ and such that $n(\gamma, z)$ is either $0$ or $1$ for any point $z$ not on $\gamma$. Suppose that $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are analytic in $\Omega$ and satisfy the inequality $|f(z)-g(z)| < |f(z)|$ on $\gamma$. Then $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ have the same number of zeros enclosed by $\gamma$. (Ahlfors)

I have some rough ideas sketched out for how to approach the problem. By hypothesis, for $|z| \leq 1$, we know $|\varphi(z)| < 1$. Now, toward using Rouche's theorem, choose $\psi(z) = z^n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. This choice of $\psi$ seems relevant to Rouche's Theorem because

$\psi(z)=z^n$ is analytic within the curve $|z| = 1$

We know exactly the number of roots $\psi(z)=z^n$ has that lie within the curve $|z|=1$

$\psi(z)$ has no poles interior to $|z|=1$. In particular, $\lim_{|z| \to 0} |\psi(z)| = 0$ and $\lim_{|z| \to 1} |\psi(z)|=1$; hence, $|\varphi(z)-\psi(z)|$ will not increase without bound, which may help to give rise to eventually showing $|\varphi(z)-\psi(z)| < |\varphi(z)|$


From the looks of it, it appears that if I can show $|\varphi(z)-\psi(z)| < |\varphi(z)|$, then I will have my result. What justification do I need to show it though?

This is indeed an application of Rouche's Theorem.
Notice that your aim is to find the roots of $z-\varphi(z)$. We want to use the hypothesis that $|\varphi(z)|<1$. Therefore, using the same notation as in the theorem above, we would like $$f(z)-g(z)=\varphi(z)$$ and $f$ a 'simple' function so that we can find its modulus at the unit circle. Your intuition about functions of the form $z^n$ is correct: concretely we will take $f(z)=z$.
Taking $g(z)=z-\varphi(z)$ we have $$|f(z)-g(z)|=|\varphi(z)|<1=|z|=|f(z)|$$ if $|z|=1$. By Rouche's Theorem $f(z)=z$ and $g(z)=z-\varphi(z)$ have the same number of roots. As $f$ has only one zero on the unit disk, $g$ has a unique root, and consequently $\varphi$ has a unique fixed point on the unit disk.

Thanks for your clear and concise answer!
